# LWJGL Eclipse: lwjgl32.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура

Tags: java, eclipse, native, lwjgl

Eclipse Neon (Пробовал и на Mars'e), LWJGL 3 Release. В Build Path'e Jar-Файл "LWJGL.jar" добавлен, нативы там же для него указаны.
Что не так?..

```
[LWJGL] Failed to load a library. Possible solutions:
    a) Set -Djava.library.path or -Dorg.lwjgl.librarypath to the directory that contains the shared libraries.
    b) Add the JAR(s) containing the shared libraries to the classpath.
[LWJGL] Enable debug mode with -Dorg.lwjgl.util.Debug=true for better diagnostics.
Exception in thread "Game" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: D:\workspace_neon_java\JGame\LWJGL\native\lwjgl32.dll: Не найдена указанная процедура
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.System.load(Unknown Source)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:110)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystemRelative(Library.java:97)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.loadSystem(Library.java:71)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Library.<clinit>(Library.java:43)
    at org.lwjgl.system.MemoryAccess.<clinit>(MemoryAccess.java:17)
    at org.lwjgl.system.Pointer.<clinit>(Pointer.java:22)
    at org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.<clinit>(GLFW.java:562)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.init(Main.java:35)
    at ru.iremit.flappy.Main.run(Main.java:25)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```